# How to be working with a generic IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, generics

I have written a function which will take a generic `IEnumerable` and map these objects (if possible) to objects I want to use for an algorithm. I don't have a lot of experience with generic objects or `IEnumerable`s, so I wanted to ask for some advice.

I have written this code:

```
public static IEnumerable<OtherObject> MyObjectToOtherObject<T>(IEnumerable<T> objects)
{
    if (objects.GetType() == typeof(MyObject))
    {
        var data = (IEnumerable<MyObject>)objects;
        return data.Select(x => new OtherObject() { // Map the attributes });
    }
    else
        return null;
}
```

This doesn't work in my code, since it returns null even though the input list is of the type `MyObject`. I just can't figure out how to cast my `IEnumerable<T>` to `IEnumerable<MyObject>`. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

I'm sorry for all the confusion. I have asked this the wrong way. Alex has helped me enough, thank you!

Comment: Use objects.OfType<Object>().Select(x => new Object1() ...))

Comment: by `Object` do you mean the built in root of all objects, or your own class? If the latter, pick a better name!!

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant, so what do you try to do other than `IEnumerable<object> result = objects;`?

Comment: I'm sorry! I changed the names for simplicity, I'll change it asap!

Comment: You;re still mixing up `Object1` and `OtherObject`.

Comment: @Jamiec excuse me, I changed my post!

Comment: `(objects.GetType() == typeof(MyObject)` should be `(objects.GetType() == typeof(IEnumerable<MyObject>)`

Comment: ... or `typeof(T) == typeof(MyObject)` ;) >ou now have edited your question to contain 3 "custom" object-classes making it even more confusing btw.

Comment: I'm sorry for asking such a confusing question. That was my bad! Alex has helped me, thanks!

Comment: @nozzleman wait for the point where you get an explanation of `OtherObject` being a subclass of `Object1` and `MyObject` being a potentially related of `T`, then everything will fall into place

Comment: Yeah, would be totally different question if the class hierarchy was known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is wrong.

```
objects.GetType() == typeof(MyObject)
```

Correct:

```
objects.GetType() == typeof(IEnumerable<T>)
```

If you need to compare type of nested items:

```
objects.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0] == typeof(MyObject)
typeof(T) == typeof(MyObject)
```

If you are checking if the type can be casted to another type:

```
objects.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].IsAssignableFrom(typeof(MyObject))
```

or just as

```
typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(MyObject))
```

Comment: I found a fault in my code. I gave the function a List<MyObject>. What do I have to do to let it check the type of objects inside the list instead of the type of IEnumerable?

Comment: Thank you for your edit! Excuse me for asking such a confusing question!

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like you need a generic method, if you always know the source and destination types, you can do this:

```
public static IEnumerable<DestObject> ObjectToObject1(IEnumerable<SourceObject> objects)
{                
    return data.Select(x => new DestObject() { // Map the attributes });

}
```

Comment: Correct, I'm going to add more types later. It doesn't even pass the if statement yet though

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is build a generic mapping method which can map any give `T` to your concrete class `Object1`. You need to provide a mapping function which does the mapping.

Say you have this (overly contrived) example:

```
public class SourceObject
{
    public string AString{get;set;}
}

public class DestObject
{
    public string TheProperty{get;set;}
}
```

And you start with an `IEnumerable<SourceObject>` your method would need to take the list, and a `Func<SourceObject,DestObject>` to do the mapping

```
var input = new List<SourceObject>(){
    new SourceObject{AString="Str1"},
    new SourceObject{AString="Str2"}
};

var result = MyObjectToOtherObject(input, x =>  new DestObject{TheProperty = x.AString});
```

This is accomplished like so:

```
public static IEnumerable<DestObject> MyObjectToOtherObject<T>(IEnumerable<T> objects, Func<T,DestObject> mapping)
{
    return data.Select(mapping);
}
```

As you can see, the separate method is more-or-less useless at this point. It's exactly what `Select` does.

Answer (score 0):

`objects` will never be of type `MyObject`, therefore

```
(objects.GetType() == typeof(MyObject))
```

will always return `false` because `object` is some generic collection (`IEnumerable<T>`).

you could try using

```
typeof(T) == typeof(MyObject)
```